# How to retrieve highest salary for each department across employees?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, rank

I am trying to compile a query which gives me the highest salary per each department and for each unique employee. The complexity is that  1 employee can be part of multiple departments.

In case the same employee has the highest salary in several departments, only the department with a lower salary should show. This is my start but I am not sure how to continue from here:

```
select max(salary) as salary, dd.dept_name,d.emp_no
from salaries s
inner join dept_emp d on
s.emp_no=d.emp_no 
inner join departments dd on
d.dept_no=dd.dept_no
group by 2,3;
```

My output is:
[image]

What should I modify from here?

Comment: Please include sample input data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an employee, you seem to only want to include the department with the smallest salary.  I would recommend using window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             rank() over (partition by dept_name order by salary desc) as seqnum_d
      from (select s.*, d.dept_name,
                   rank() over (partition by dept_name order by salary) as seqnum_ed
            from salaries s join
                 dept_emp d
                 on s.emp_no = d.emp_no join
                 departments dd 
                 d.dept_no = dd.dept_no
           ) s
      where seqnum_ed = 1
     ) s
where seqnum_d = 1;
```

Comment: It does not work. It states that dept_name is unknown. Also, I . do not see the joins anywhere as there are 3 tables involved here (see original post).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select m.salary, m.emp_no, salary.dept_name from salary,
(select emp_no, min(salary) salary from salary group by emp_no) m
where
m.emp_no=salary.emp_no and m.salary=salary.salary;
```